Position for Filter after AuthorizationServerContextFilter in Spring Authorization server
I want to add a filter after the AuthorizationServerContextFilter.class in Spring Authorization server.
I cannot add it directly after this class as it is not public.
Which is another possible class down the filter chain where this is possible?
The filter I want to add is a Tenant Identification Filter while trying to implement multi tenancy.
